# Convert a series of PNGs to an animated gif or video file

Tags: video, automation, imagemagick, animation, blender

I have a series of PNG image files that I want to convert into animation.

What is the best way to convert them into a GIF?

Also I have tried various tools to convert them into a video file (like ffmpeg), however they produce a poor quality video. Using the Video Sequence Editor in Blender produces the desired quality however I do not know how to automate this.

(Using ImageMagick's convert takes too long, is there a way to speed it up?)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert an image sequence into an animated .gif, the easiest way is via ImageMagick's `convert` command:

```
convert -delay 5 -layers Optimize $FILE_LIST foo.gif
```

The above command combines all of the files into an optimized animated .gif with a 5 millisecond frame time.  You can also do more complicated things with timing via something like:

```
convert -layers Optimize -delay 5 frame1.png frame2.png -delay 10 frame3.png animation.gif
```

which gives a 5ms delay for frame1 and frame2, and a 10ms delay for frame3.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about quality, don't convert to GIF.

To create a video, you can use `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i 'image%d.png' -vcodec copy out.mkv
```

`-f image2 -i 'image%d.png'` tells `ffmpeg` to read the PNG images `image1.png`, `image2.png`, etc. in sequence. `-vcodec copy` losslessly stores the images in a video stream. The resulting video is playable in `vlc` or `totem`.

Since the image data is just copied, this will be very **fast** and of course **lossless**.

(See ["How do I encode single pictures into movies?"](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC14) in ffmpeg's docs.)